# pydev breakpoint not hit

Tags: debugging, pydev, breakpoints

I have the scenario where my python application is running in a winXP virtual machine that is hosted on a linux machine. The linux machine runs Eclipse with pydevd.

The path on the linux machine is /home//project
The path on the winXP machine is a mapped F: drive that is pointing to /home//project

Having followed the instructions I can remote debug, step into methods etc. However when I set a breakpoint I get:

pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: f:\home\\project\.py (will have no effect)

Somehow it seems to attach the f: drive to the unix path?